# Java: Equivalent to Python's str.format()

Tags: java, python, string

In Python, there is a very nice method which simplifies creation of strings, making their code beautiful and readable.

For example, the following code will print `ExampleProgram -E- Cannot do something`

```
def print_msg(msg_type, msg):
    print 'ExampleProgram -{0}- {1}'.format(msg_type, msg)
print_msg('E', 'Cannot do something')
```

I.e. I can specify "slots" within the string, using the `{x}` syntax, where `x` is the parameter index, and then it returns an new string, in which it replaces these slots with the parameters passed to the `.format()` method.

Currently with my Java knowledge, I would implement such a method this ugly way:

```
void printMsg(String type, String msg) {
    System.out.println("ExampleProgram -" + type + "- " + msg);
}
```

Is there something equivalent to Python's `.format()` string method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) has the exact usage.

```
 int planet = 7;
 String event = "a disturbance in the Force";

 String result = MessageFormat.format(
     "At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.",
     planet, new Date(), event);
```

You can simple use `{0123}` without extras.
The output is:

```
 At 12:30 PM on Jul 3, 2053, there was a disturbance in the Force on planet 7.
```

Answer (score 6):

```
System.out.format("ExampleProgram - %s - %s ",type, msg);
```

You can use the format method from the `System.out`.

Then use the following:

```
 String output = String.format("ExampleProgram - %s - %s ", type, msg);
```

Here `type` and `msg` are of `String` type.

For any integer use `%d`, and floating point `%f`, and `String` `%s`.

You can find all the information about different way of formatting output in the java documentation. [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to just store it in a new string?

Comment: @SomethingSomething I have updated the answer, please check. It also include the link to java documentation.

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
String s = String.format("something %s","name");
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks pretty similar. Python accepts only strings - so it seems that like your example, I can use the `%s` and then just to pass strings. The only disadvantage here is that if I want to repeat the same value many times in the string, I must pass it again and again, while in Python I could just repeat the slot `{0} {0}`

Comment: @SomethingSomething You can do something similar in Java; take a look at [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for examples.

Answer (score 2):

how about System.out.printf()? then you can use c style formatting

Comment: Thank you! I prefer some formatting in which I can repeat the slots' indices many times and which simply uses strings. It is also a nice solution