# Are there other ways to concatenate inofrmation when I am going to print other than +, like System.out.println("hello" + etc + variable))

Tags: java, concatenation

Before I learnt the basics in python and there are several ways to concatenate information like:

```
name = "Eduardo"
surname = "Garcia"

print("Hello " + name + " " + surname)
print("Hello {} {}".format(name, surname))
```

I like this one

```
print(f"Hello {name} {surname}")
```

But I am making a course in java and the teacher says that the only way to do it is with +

But that sounds strange to me. Are there other ways to do it like in python with .format or f.

Thank you.

I am learning the basics in java. I just want to understand how it works.

Comment: Make sure you are using Java 8 and then System.out.printf will work - but it still isn't what you were hoping for.

Comment: No. Java uses `+` as the concatenation operator. `printf` will let you output strings without it, but that's not concatenation (which is also true of your Python example - the second and third calls to `print` do not concatenate, but use a format string).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324007/java-equivalent-of-pythons-format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281826/java-equivalent-to-pythons-str-format

Comment: Here is one that has a similar format to you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html  I don't see anything that allows you to specify the variables inside the format string and not have any other parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Java has `System.out.printf`, which is more-or-less (not exactly) like every other printf that's out there (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)).

The String class has `String.format` (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)).

With respect to what your teacher tells you - literally, they are correct.  Formatting is **not** concatenation; however, to achieve a particular result, you can often choose between formatting and concatenation.